# Проверка на успешное добавление данных

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Я знаю, какой функцией можно осуществить данную проверку, но не совсем понимаю как правильно ее прикрутить к уже существующей функции добавления данных.
Имеется функция, соответственно в общем файле всех функций.

```
func {
    public static function getData($dbh){
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Запрос на добавление");
      $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
      return $stmt->execute();
  }

}
```

где $dbh - подключение к базе.
И соответственно, происходит ее вызов в файле **index.php** ;

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['sendform'])) {
   func::getData($dbh);
}
?>
```

Заранее, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static function getData($dbh){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("Запрос на добавление");
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    return $stmt->execute() ? TRUE : FALSE;
}

if (func::getData($dbh)) {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: похоже что работает, спасибо.